What is the filiation of contemporary English-speaking countries typology?
What is the filiation of the contemporary English-speaking countries typology?
IMU, the representative of the contemporary English-speaking countries typology are Keenan, Comrie, Dryer and Dixon.
But I could not find in what kind of linguistic tradition these authors were trained in (Generative Grammar, European structuralism, American structuralism, etc.), not did I find that they were directly related to the "father" of contemporary typology, J. Greenberg.
William Croft, also broadly recognized in typology, was trained by Greenberg, nonetheless.

Found one filiation for some of them: His [= Greenberg] more enduring legacy is in reshaping typology and universals research, and deeply influencing "West Coast Functionalists" such as Bernard Comrie, Charles Li, T. Givon, Sandra Thompson, and many other functionalists such as Joan Bybee, as well as European typologists such as Hans-Jakob Seiler and Bernd Heine.  https://www.ruf.rice.edu/~kemmer/Found/lineages.html

But not for Dixon and Dryer
